# Cookies getting updated instead of adding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I am working on a voting mechanism application in my MVC project, I have a requirement that the users are allowed to vote only once in a browser, if he reaches the voting page for the second time in the same browser he shouldnot be able to vote but if in another browser he logins and he should be able to vote again. 
 
 To do that I have used the Cookies to handle this scenario. What I did was I have added the UserID to the cookie and in the View page i am checking whether Vote button is visible or not. 
 
 My view is

```
@if ((ViewData["CookieData"] == null) || (ViewData["CookieData"].ToString() != Session["LoginPersonID"].ToString()))
{    
        <button name="button" value="Insert" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit your choices ?.');">Vote Now!!</button>
        <br />  
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to Home Page", "EmployeeHomePage", "Employee", new { logedinperson = Session["LoginPersonID"] }, null);
}
```

and My Controller is

```
public void AddCookie()
{            
    HttpCookie MyCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie", Session["LoginPersonID"].ToString());           
    MyCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);           
    Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);
    ViewData["CookieData"] = MyCookieCollection;       
}
```

when the First User say PersonA logins in Firefox and votes, his personid is stored in the cookie, so if he tries to reach the voting page again the Vote button will be invisible, but then he tries open on Google Chrome he can then vote.Thats also working as expected. Now when the PersonB login in Firefox and votes his personid is updated in the cookie, so he also cannot vote in the same browser for the second time. 
  
  But my exact problem is when the PersonA logins again to Firefox he is able to vote because the cookie has been updated with the PersonB's id. So is there anyway how can I restrict both PersonA and PersonB if they have voted already in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't distinguish between users when naming your cookie. There should be one cookie per user OR you should build a list of users in that single cookie -- but keep in mind that a cookie is limited to 4K in size.

So if you change the line

```
HttpCookie MyCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie",
                      Session["LoginPersonID"].ToString());
```

to something like this

```
var userName = Session["LoginPersonID"].ToString();
HttpCookie MyCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie-" + userName,
                      "Voted");
```

then it should work (bearing in mind that you also have to modify the code that reads the cookie).

Comment: I have tried as follows, still not getting

var LoginPID = Session["LoginPersonID"].ToString();
HttpCookie MyCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie-" + LoginPID ,
                      "Voted");
MyCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);           
Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);
ViewData["CookieData"] = MyCookieCollection; 

Is this the one you meant ?

Answer (score 1):

One problem that I see is that you never read the cookie from the request. Your controller is always creating the cookie and sending it back with the response. Instead you should first check to see whether a cookie exists and then act accordingly.

The other aspect is that if you want the cookie to be per account you need to create a different cookie for each account (i.e. construct the cookie name based on the userid or username), or to store all ids/usernames in the cookie and then check each against each one.

Comment: How can I create the different cookie for each account??

Answer (score 0):

## The idea

Store both the IDs in one cookie. When the cookie is an ID list (e.g. comma-separated), it could hold voting restrictions on more than one person. You have to check that the person trying to vote is not in the list.

Of course this works only under assumption that no ID contains chosen delimiter, in this case comma. If comma is not the case, choose pipe or whatever character satisfies this property.

## Algoritm

Cookie mechanism is designed to store key-value pairs. Both key and value are strings. If you want to store a comma-separated list of IDs in your cookie, you have to join them using comma as a delimiter (`String.join(",", ids)`). First read the original value of your cookie, split it in commas, then add the new ID (if not already there) and then join the list and update the cookie.

## Implementation

```
public void AddCookie() {
    HttpCookie MyCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
    var userName = Session["LoginPersonID"].ToString();
    var originalCookieContents = ViewData["CookieData"].ToString();
    var ids = new HashSet<String>(originalCookieContents.Split(','));
    ids.Add(userName);
    MyCookie.Value = String.Join(",", ids);
    MyCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);
    ViewData["CookieData"] = MyCookie.Value;
}
```

Do not forget to update your view code accordingly! Construct `HashSet` ids and use its `Contains` method.